# passing null structure pointer ctypes

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am writing a Python wrapper for cpp APIs in that for one API I am trying to pass a NULL structure pointer as a parameter. Not sure how we can achieve that in Python.

Below is my sample implementation:

**cpp_header.hpp**

```cpp
typedef enum {
    E_FLAG_ON = 0,
    E_FLAG_OFF
} option;

typedef struct {
    float *a;
    float b;
    char *file_path; 
    option flag;
} inputs;

// API
int op_init(const inputs*);
```

This is what happening inside the init API:

**Implementation.cpp**

```cpp
int op_init(const inputs* usr_ptr) {
    internal_opration_read_set(&local_struct) { // local struct variable
         // read one input file and update the structure values
    }
    if (usr_prt !=  NULL) {
        internal_opration_update_set(usr_ptr, &local_struct) {
            // update the values only if i send NOT NULL structure
        }
    }
}
```

From cpp test application I'm passing NULL structure to initialize.

**test.cpp**

```
int main() {
    inputs *usr_cfg = NULL;
    op_init(usr_cfg);
}
```

**ctypes_imple.py**

```py
From ctypes import *

class inputs(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('a', POINTER(c_float)),
                ('b', c_float),
                ('file_path', c_char_p),
                ('flag', option)]

# loading so file
so_lib = CDLL('some so')
# how we can initialize NULL structure pointer here?
so_lib.op_init() # how to send structure pointer as argument?
```

NOTE: this API reads inputs from a file and updates values to a structure in C.  I am clueless how we can achieve the same in a Python wrapper? I mean updating values from so file runtime to a ctypes Python class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `None` to pass a null pointer:

```py
so_lib.op_init(None)
```

To send the actual structure instantiate one and send it.  Best to define `.argtypes` and `restype` as well so `ctypes` doesn't have to guess and can perform better error checking:

```py
so_lib.op_init.argtypes = POINTER(inputs),
so_lib.op_init.restype = c_int

arg = inputs() # all initialized to zero/null by default.
so_lib.op_init(arg)
```

Comment: I tried giving 'None', the memory passed from here is not same when i debug it from c source side. Since memory is not same code is not working as expected.
Any way that we can pass same address to c source?

Address in python:
{} <cparam 'P' (0xffffb39b1270)>
{} <core.LP_sc_app_config_t object at 0xffffb39b1440>
{} <cparam 'P' (0xffffb39b1540)>
{} <core.LP_sc_app_config_t object at 0xffffb39b13b0>


Address received in C source:
[PY WRAPPER DEBUG] Recevied address: 0xffffb39b1420

Comment: @soundarrajanv `None` is a null pointer and will be address zero on C side. None of the above relates to your question. Edit your question with a [mcve] if you want more help. Addresses of Python objects won’t match the addresses of the C-translated memory. Use `ctypes.addressof()` to print the C address.